# iOS: updating constraints and frame at the same time

Tags: ios, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have in my app one `UITextField` on the left and one `UIButton` on the right. The textfield is anchored on the left at the superview (a container view) and in the right to the button.
So in the left of textfield there is a

> leading space = 0 in relation of container

and on the right a

> trailing space = 0 in relation of button

but if I move the button on the right way, changing the x origin value, why the textfield don't enlarge its width?

(obviously the button has its constraints about width and height and for position, but not that lock the textfield)

so if I do this

```
self.mybutton.frame = CGRectMake(self.mybutton.frame.origin.x+100, self.mybutton.frame.origin.y, self.mybutton.frame.size.width, self.mybutton.frame.size.height);
```

the button moved in the right direction but the textfield seems to doesn't enlarge its width,.
Do you know why?

Comment: Do it the other way around give textfield a width constraint and change it programatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try animating the button's trailing constraint?

Like so (I changed the constraint inside an animation block for illustration purposes):

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(
    5.0,
    animations: {
        self.buttonTrailingMarginConstraint.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // Necessary when changing constraints.
    }
)
```

Final result:

[image: Example]

Git clone project: https://github.com/backslash-f/animating-constraints

Answer (score 2):

Working with both Auto Layout and programmatic positioning/sizing can create a lot of headaches. Part of this is because you have created constraints in Auto Layout, which are basically "rules" that your app must follow when laying out all of it's views, and when you change the frame, bounds, or center properties you may be invalidating those rules. But since Auto Layout is not constantly recalculating the layout of your views, problems may go unnoticed until a layout recalculation is triggered.

So to answer your question, changing the frame of the button does not change the text because Auto Layout has no idea that anything has changed. Plus you haven't changed the constraints on the button so if you did call `- (void) setNeedsUpdateConstraints` on your text field and button, the change you are looking for won't happen. The button will move back to it's initial position, the one you set with constraints.

What you may want to do is create an `IBOutlet` on whatever is controlling how the button gets positioned on the x-axis (i.e. its trailing space...if that is what you are using). Then instead of doing:

```
self.mybutton.frame = CGRectMake(self.mybutton.frame.origin.x+100, self.mybutton.frame.origin.y, self.mybutton.frame.size.width, self.mybutton.frame.size.height);
```

You could do something like:

```
self.mybuttonXconstraint.constant = self.mybuttonXconstraint.constant + 100
[self.parentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints]
```

The second line is to ensure that Auto Layout knows a constraint has been changed and that it should recalculate the layout for any views involved with the parent's constraints.

This may be of interest to you as well - [iOS Developer Library - Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1)